# Airtable add column dynamically

Tags: node.js, airtable

I have a base in airtable and now I need to up columns(fields) programmatically.
For example sql has a query for this operation

```
ALTER TABLE Employees
  ADD EmployeeID numeric NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1)
```

Is there a API for Airtable to do such operations?

Answer (score 0):

Airtable offers an API to use, *but not for adding columns*. There is a Node.js package and several other programing libraries available on [Github](https://github.com/Airtable/airtable.js).

They have official Doc's as well  https://airtable.com/api. With out getting creative and hacking something together, it is not possible to modify a table’s schema via the API. So you cannot do actions like add columns or modify the values in an existing table.

```
var Airtable = require('airtable');
var base = new Airtable({apiKey: 'YOUR_API_KEY'}).base('app$$%&#*(@');

base('Employees').update('EmployeeID', {
  "EmployeeID": "Number"
}, function(err, record) {
    if (err) { console.error(err); return; }
    console.log(record.get('EmployeeID'));
});
```

Here is a quick snippet of an update function to update a record.

Comment: This snippet results in `{ error: "NOT_FOUND", message: "Could not find what you are looking for", statusCode: 404 }` if there's no column named `EmployeeID`.  Also, even if a column named `EmployeeID` already exists, in which case you'd only be changing its type (not adding it, per the OP), this is the message you get.  So this isn't the workaround alluded to in your comment on Emanuele's answer.

Answer (score -1):

you can't update dynamically an Airtable table. You can update only the existent field values. The response from Nick C is the syntax to PATCH a record.

Comment: edited below, There are workarounds, to do some dynamic based editing and updating via the API though, But the scope is beyond most developers need or use in time & resources